# Apache Solr [embedded] collection not found error in test cases

Tags: scala, solr, solr4, solrcloud

I am tring to start the Solr Server in beforeALL method but it is giving collection not found error.

Here is the code snippet

```
var server: EmbeddedSolrServer = _

  override def beforeAll() {

    val container = new CoreContainer("testConf")
    container.load()
    server = new EmbeddedSolrServer(container, "collection1")
  }

  test("") {

    val param = new ModifiableSolrParams()
    param.set("q", "search")
    server.getCoreContainer.load()
    println(server.query(param).getResults.get(0).getFirstValue("title").toString)
    assert(true)
  }

  override def afterAll(): Unit = {
    server.close()
  }
```

i am following step from `https://wiki.searchtechnologies.com/index.php/Unit_Testing_with_Embedded_Solr`

Here is the error stack

> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: No such core: collection1   at
>   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.embedded.EmbeddedSolrServer.request(EmbeddedSolrServer.java:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:149)
>     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.query(SolrClient.java:942)
>     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.query(SolrClient.java:957)

Any help will be appretiacted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside directory called "collection1", you have to insert a `core.properties` file in which you write the follow property: `name=collection1`.

Without this file, you get the SolrException.